# $MongoDB $lookup foreach element in array on the same collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of users where each element has a list of contacts, I would like to create an aggregation which, given the id of the user, makes a $ lookup for each contact and returns the information of the user from the same collection of users

the user collection looks like

```js
[
    {
        '_id': 1,
        'username': 'user 1',
        'contacts_list': [
            {
                'contact_id': '2'
            },
            {
                'contact_id: 3
             }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        '_id': 2,
        'username': 'user 2',
        'contacts_list': [
            {
                'contact_id': 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        '_id': 3,
        'username': 'user 3',
        'contacts_list': [
            {
                'contact_id': 1
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

i tried something like this

```js
[
  {
    '$match': {
      '_id': 1
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$contacts_list', 
      'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true
    }
  }, {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'users', 
      'localField': 'contacts_list.contact_id', 
      'foreignField': '_id', 
      'as': 'contact'
    }
  }, {
    '$group': {
      '_id': '$_id',
      '$push': {
        'username': 'contact.username'
       }
]
```

but I only got the information from one of the users, thanks for the help

Comment: your question is not clear, can you post expected result.

Comment: There are some typos in your code.  Compare what you have with https://mongoplayground.net/p/29bKEr_RXAW